# Parity and the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, graph-theory, graph-colorings, axiom-of-choice, bipartite-graphs

**Motivation.** The *three-dimensional cube* can be formalized by $\mathcal P(\{0,1,2\})$ where vertices $x,y\in\mathcal P(\{0,1,2\})$ are connected by an edge if and only if their symmetric difference $x\mathbin\Delta y := (x\setminus y) \cup (y\setminus x)$ contains exactly $1$ element. If we want to assign to each vertex one of the colors *black* and *white* such that no two vertices connected by an edge get the same color, we use the concept of *parity*: color any vertices containing an *even* number of elements *black*, and the rest *white*. This "parity algorithm" works for any $\mathcal P(X)$ where $X$ is a finite set. But what happens in the infinite case?

**Formal version.** Consider the following statement:

> (Parity principle:) If $X\neq \emptyset$ is a set, then there is $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ such that whenever $a,b\in \mathcal P(X)$ with $a\mathbin\Delta b = \{x\}$ for some $x\in X$, then $\mathcal B$ contains exactly one of $a$, $b$.

The Parity Principle is a theorem in $(\textsf{ZFC})$. Does the Parity Principle imply the Axiom of Choice in $(\textsf{ZF})$?

Comment: The Parity Principle, and the more general proposition that every (not necessarily finite) graph without odd cycles is $2$-colorable, follow from the axiom of choice for $2$-element sets, which does not even imply the axiom of choice for $3$-element sets, much less the full Axiom of Choice.

Comment: To explain @bof's comment (which I suggest he post as an answer rather than a comment): consider the even-finite-difference equivalence classes for subsets of $X$, and form pairs of such classes when they have odd differences. By AC for pairs, you can pick one class from each pair, and this gives a parity assignment.

Comment: TeX note: $a\Delta b$ `a\Delta b` for the symmetric difference does not space as one might hope, because TeX does not know that $\Delta$ is meant to be a binary operator.  You can explicitly tell it so using $a\mathbin\Delta b$ `a\mathbin\Delta b`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice But is $a\mathbin\Delta b$ or $a\mathbin\triangle b$ the best notation for the symmetric difference?

Comment: @bof I think that $\Delta$ is the best, since my understanding is that it is derived from being the delta[, difference, change...] between the sets. However, I am a sucker for symmetric notation for symmetric operations...

Comment: @CalliopeRyan-Smith The symbol for set membership is derived from the Greek letter $\epsilon$, but we typically use the more stylized symbol $\in$. In the same spirit, I prefer $\triangle$ to $\Delta$ for symmetric difference.

Comment: You don’t need to specifically exclude $X = \varnothing$. The principle is vacuously satisfied in that case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Parity Principle follows from the axiom $\mathbf C_2$ (defined below) which is weaker than the Axiom of Choice. I don't know whether the Parity Principle implies $\mathbf C_2$, but that's another question.

For $n\ge2$ let $\mathbf C_n$ denote Mostowski's axiom of choice for $n$-element sets, which says that every collection of $n$-element sets has a choice function; see Andrzej Mostowski, [Axiom of choice for finite sets](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm33/fm33120.pdf), Fund. Math. 33 (1945), 137-168, and John Truss, [Finite axioms of choice](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484373900077), Ann. Math. Logic 6 (1973), 147-176. These axioms $\mathbf C_n$ are weaker than the full Axiom of Choice; indeed, $\mathbf C_2$ does not even imply $\mathbf C_3$ (although $\mathbf C_2$ is equivalent to $\mathbf C_4$) in **ZF**.

Inasmuch as the hypercube graph contains no odd cycles, it will suffice to prove the following:

**Theorem (ZF).** The axiom $\mathbf C_2$ is equivalent to the assertion that every (finite or infinite) graph with no odd cycles is $2$-colorable.

**Proof.** First, suppose $\mathbf C_2$ holds, and consider a graph with no odd cycles. Note that each connected component admits exactly two proper blue/red $2$-colorings. Choose a proper $2$-coloring for each component and take the union to get a proper $2$-coloring of the whole graph.

Conversely, suppose that every graph with no odd cycles is $2$-colorable. In particular, every $1$-regular graph (matching) is $2$-colorable, and the assertion that every matching is $2$-colorable is plainly equivalent to the assertion that every collection of *disjoint* $2$-element sets has a choice function, which is equivalent to $\mathbf C_2$.

Comment: For an explicit graph without odd cycles whose chromatic number is uncountable without assuming AC, see Section 4 of the paper by Soifer and Shelah at https://shelah.logic.at/files/95685/E51.pdf.