# The Parity Principle and $\mathbf{C}_2$ (choice for $2$-sets)

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

The Parity Principle states that

> if $X\neq \emptyset$ is a set, then there is $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ such that whenever $a,b\in \mathcal P(X)$ with $a\mathbin\Delta b = \{x\}$ for some $x\in X$, then $\mathcal B$ contains exactly one of $a$, $b$.

The Axiom of Choice for $2$-element sets $\mathbf{C}_2$ is strictly weaker than the original Axiom of Choice, and $\mathbf{C}_2$ [implies](https://mathoverflow.net/a/453944/8628) the Parity Principle.

Does the Parity Principle imply $\mathbf{C}_2$?

Comment: Have you asked the question you intended? It seems we know that it does by the linked question, as you say.

Comment: Thanks @JoelDavidHamkins for spotting my mistake, I intended to ask about the other implication and have corrected my error.

Comment: @AndreasLietz I don't follow. The two different possibilities will have the same parity.

Comment: @AndreasLietz: I don’t follow either, but for a different reason than Elliot Glazer.  In trying to proving $\mathbf{C}_2$ (or even full choice) over a well-ordered base by induction, the difficulty at limit steps isn’t in choosing the “next point”, it’s in picking earlier choices for all previous steps together.

Comment: Youre right, I was talking nonsense!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Over ZFA, the Parity Principle is strictly weaker. We'll show it follows from Multiple Choice, the assertion that for any family of nonempty sets $\mathcal{F},$ there is $g: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow [\bigcup \mathcal{F}]^{<\omega} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ such that $g(S) \subseteq S$ for all $S \in \mathcal{F}.$ Multiple Choice holds in the second Fraenkel Model ($\mathcal{N}_2$ in *Consequences of the Axiom of Choice*), in which $\mathbf{C}_2$ fails badly (in particular, its atoms are a family of Russell socks).

Fix $X.$ Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ defined by $S \sim T$ if $S \triangle T \in [X]^{<\omega}.$ Let
$\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{P}(X) / \sim$ and let $g: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow [\bigcup \mathcal{F}]^{<\omega} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ be such that $g(S) \subset S$ for all $S \in \mathcal{F}.$ Define a choice function
$h: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \bigcup \mathcal{F}$ by $h(S)=\bigcup g(S).$ Then
$\mathcal{B}:=\{S \subseteq X: |S \triangle h([S]_{\sim} )| \in 2\mathbb{Z}\}$ is as desired.

Note that over ZF, Multiple Choice is equivalent to full Choice, so this approach doesn't immediately separate Parity Principle from $\mathbf{C}_2$ over ZF.

Comment: In human language the Axiom of Multiple Choice says you can assign to each nonempty set a finite nonempty subset. Since the connected components of the Hamming graph on $2^X$ are sublattices, if you choose a nonempty finite subset of each component, you can choose an element of each component by taking the supremum. As the graph has no odd cycles, once you establish a base point in each component, there is a unique proper $2$-coloring with all the base points colored blue. I post this redundant comment for the benefit of those like me who get a headache from deciphering a lot of notation.

Comment: @bof Thank you!